# Using a feature as Input vs. using it to build Several Machines on SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am using SVM to predict the arrival time of a bus to a bus stop in its route. After doing a lot of research and reading some papers I still have a key doubt about how to model my system.

We've decided which features to use and we are in the process of gathering the data required to perform the regression, but what is confusing us are the implications or consequences of using some features as input for the SVM or building separated machines based on some of these features.

For instance, in this [paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15472450600981009#preview) the authors built 4 SVMs for predicting bus arrival times: one for rush hour on sunny days, rush hour on rainy days, off-rush hour on sunny days and the last one for off-rush hours and rainy days.

But on a [following paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/atr.136/abstract) on the same subejct they decided to use a single SVM with the weather condition and the rush/off-rush hour as input instead of breaking it in 4 SVMs as before.

When to choose one of these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Most important question: what is the data like?
Second question: what model do you expect to capture this?

So if you want to use SVMs for some reason, keep in mind their basic mechanism is linear, and can only capture non-linear phenomena if data is transformed by a suitable kernel.

For a particular problem at hand that means:

1. Do you have reason (plots, insights in the problem nature) to believe your problem is linear(ly separable)? Just use one linear svm.
2. Do you have reason your problem consist of several linear subproblems? Use a linear svm on each of the subproblems.
3. Does your data seem non-linearly grouped? Try an svm with something like rbf kernel.

Of course, you can just plug in and try, but checking the above may increase understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular problem I would go for single SVM.

With my not so extensive experience, I would consider breaking a problem in several SVMs for following reasons:

1. The classes are too different, or there are classes and subclasses in your problem.
   E.g. in my case: there are several types of antibodies in a microscope image and they all may be positive or negative. So instead of defining A_Pos, A_Neg, B_Pos, B_Neg, ... I decide first if the image is positive or negative and determine the type in second SVM.
2. The feature extraction is too expensive. Provided you have groups of classes, which may be identified with fever features. Instead of extracting all features for a single machine, you may first extract only a small subset, and if required (result not with high enough probability) extract further features.
3. Decide whether the instance belongs to problem at all. Make a model containing one class and all instances of training set. If the instance to be classified is an outlier, stop. Otherwise classify with 2nd SVM containing all classes.

The key-word is "cascaded SVM"